# Wordpress Ninja forms post process hook doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm trying run a simple function when form is submitted. 
I have my own simple plugin, which is activated, I've tried do to this from Wordpress admin panel, and setup WP HOOK in Ninja Forms plugin actions - but it didn't work either.

I've setup simple form with id = 2; Only checkbox and submit button.
Only `ninja_forms_after_form_display` was called on init. When I've submitted form none of process hooks callbacks was activated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

```php
function action_process_callback( $form_id ) {
    echo "action callback";
};

// add the action
add_action( 'ninja_forms_after_form_display', 'action_process_callback', 2 );


add_action( 'ninja_forms_pre_process', 'action_process_callback', 2);
add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'action_process_callback', 2 );
add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', 'action_process_callback', 2);


add_action( 'ninja_forms_processing', 'action_process_callback', 2 );

add_action( 'ninja_forms_after_submission', 'action_process_callback', 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of you would step up to the same problem. It turned out that any `echo` called by Ninja Forms using WP Hook is somehow 'silenced' by NinjaForms. Switching my debug method to `error_log`, showed that callback actually was called.